# Is there a view that shows road density?

Tags: simcity-2013

I am upgrading my roads and find it difficult to tell whether a road is low/med or high density.

Using the upgrade road tool I click on roads in the area I am upgrading until I feel I have upgraded them all. Sometimes I reclick on a road I have upgraded already "to be sure".

Is there a view that shows road density? Is there an easier way to upgrade roads?

I find the upgrade road tool a little annoying as the dialogue that pops up covers the area I am upgrading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no view to specifically show road density. The best you can do is to open the traffic view, and see where your bottlenecks are taking place.

The only other visual cues are the appearance of the road itself, and the density of the buildings forming along it.

I'm also not 100% sure where it is, but I think there is a view option to hide buildings and just show zones. This may make it easier for you to see the roads.